# (ZEND) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:

Tags: sql, zend-db, zend-framework

When I try to execute this Sql-Statement I have this error :

***Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id_actualite' in where clause is ambiguous' in C:\wamp\www\contradictors\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234***

Here is my code :

```
    <?php
        class Critique extends Zend_Db_Table
        {
             protected $_name = "Critique" ;

             public function select_critique($limit1, $limit2)
             {
                   $db = $this -> getDefaultAdapter() ;
                   $last_actu = $db -> select()
                                    -> order('id_actualite DESC')
                                    -> from('Actualite')
                                    -> limit($limit1) ;
                   $last_actu = $last_actu -> query() ;
                   $last_actu = $last_actu -> fetch() ;

                   $select = $db -> select()
                                 -> from('Critique')
                                 -> order('id_critique DESC')
                                 -> join('Actualite', 'Critique.id_actualite = Actualite.id_actualite')
                                 -> where('id_actualite = ' . $last_actu['id_actualite'])
                                 -> limit($limit2) ;
                  return $select -> query() ;
             }
        }
   ?>
```

I don't have any idea about this error :(
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two columns named `id_actualite`: `Critique.id_actualite` and `Actualite.id_actualite`, so the where clause

```
where('id_actualite = ' . $last_actu['id_actualite'])
```

is ambiguous. Try changing it to

```
where('Critique.id_actualite = ' . $last_actu['id_actualite'])
```

or

```
where('Actualite.id_actualite = ' . $last_actu['id_actualite'])
```

Comment: @Mehdi Your welcome. Please accept the answer if it works. Accepting and upvoting are the usual ways of thanking.